# get id for element that was clicked

Tags: jquery

How do I get the id of the element that was clicked when I have a function like this?

```
$("#btnOne, #btnTwo").on("click", "input.select", function () {
```

I tried:

```
this.id;
```

and

```
$(this).attr("id");
```

Here is the html

```
<div id="TransferOwnershipBox" title="Transfer Ownership">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbSearchField" Text="Search..." ClientIDMode="Static" Width="400px" runat="server" CssClass="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btnSearch" data-str="tblOwnerSearchResults" value="Search" Class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="tblOwnerSearchResults" data-str="ownerId" data-dataItem="id" style="border: none; width: 100%; padding: 2px;"></table>
</div>


<!-----COURSE DIRECTOR----->
<div id="CourseDirectorBox" title="Directors">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbDirector" Text="Search..." ClientIDMode="Static" Width="400px" runat="server" CssClass="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btnDirectorSearch" data-str="tblDirectorSearchResults" value="Search" Class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="tblDirectorSearchResults" data-str="source" data-dataItem="DisplayName" style="border: none; width: 100%; padding: 2px;"></table>              
</div>
```

But I am not getting any id from either.

Thanks

Comment: Do(es) the `input.select` select element(s) have any ID(s)?  Both ways are correct, so either your handler gets never called or the elements don't have IDs.

Comment: `$(this).attr("id");` should do it.

Comment: I added the HTML above

Comment: I don't see any `input` element with class `select`. Neither do I see elements with those IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I cant see your HTML I'll offer an example:

HTML

```
<div id="ID1">Hello World</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

Tested and works...I did need to wrap the div click selector in quotes (duh!)

Again with respect to my comment, this approach is probably the cleanest for a simple jQuery onClick event.  If you must use the .on() binding method for jQuery it's quite similar.

### Delegates

---

In order to use the .on() delegate method of click event binding, the syntax (as you have in your question) would look something like this:

HTML

```
<div id="myTable">
    <div class="table-row" id="a">Hello World</div>
    <div class="table-row" id="b">I'm a delegate!</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myTable").on("click", "div", function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

This way of event-binding allows for any elements that are descendants (children) of your parent event handler (in our case, #myTable) to be bound as well.  The advantage is any children created and added to the event handler AFTER the handlers creation are also bound.  It can potentially be a godsend for saving time.  Basically, it allows for a quick way to bind events to dynamic objects.  Try it out!

Answer (score 2):

You use the delegated syntax of the `.on()`.

The event occurs on the `input.select` element not the `#btnOne` or`#btnTwo`.

If you want the containers (*`#btnOne` or `btnTwo`*) id use

```
$("#btnOne, #btnTwo").on("click", "input.select", function () {  
   var id = $(this).closest('#btnOne, #btnTwo')[0].id;
});
```

---

Use [@undefined's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15691122/128165) if you are using version 1.7 and higher (*which you should be*)

Comment: Oh ok, so there is no way to tell which button was clicked? -thanks

Comment: @999cm999 are the `input.select` the elements with id `btnOne` and `btnOne`? Or are those ids on the containers of those `input.select` elements ?

Comment: I've answered your question more thoroughly after your above comment...check out my edited post :)

Answer (score 2):

`this` in your code refers to the `input` element not the `#btnOne` and `#btnTwo` elements, you can use `delegateTarget` property of event object which refers to the target element of the event delegation.

```
$("#btnOne, #btnTwo").on("click", "input.select", function(event) {
    console.log(event.delegateTarget.id);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WNC5y/

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
$("#btnOne, #btnTwo").click(function(){
    $(this).attr("id");
});
```